# Wireless USB card not detected on Kali (armel) running on Android

Tags: android, wifi, kali-linux, arm, drivers

I have a "TL-WN22N" that i want to use it with my Xiaomi Mi4i running Kali-rolling that was installed using "LinuxDeploy", What i want to do is to connect my wireless card to it, But obviously nothing happen when plugging it in, So whats going in my head is that i need to make the device recognize the wireless card by installing the card's driver on the host "Android", If its correct how can i do so, and if not what should i do to make it work?

Comment: This is off topic here. You need more of a tech support forum.

Comment: why its off topic?

Comment: The question is about connecting a Linux OS running on a Xiaomi Android to a specific wireless card. The fact that the Linux happens to be a security tool-focused OS is irrelevant. This is a straight up Linux/Xiaomi/Android/wireless card question. https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic may help explain.

Comment: the question needs to be edited, now that you've got the where i am going with this. do you have the answer to this?

Comment: Installing drivers is not a security question. This is a Linux/device question. I will migrate.